# Would a light sabre/plasma jet melt a window without shattering it?

Tags: magnetic-fields, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, plasma-physics

Serious question! Is there a temperature/impact surface area relationship at which glass melts by heat, rather than shattering by force?

Comment: See [this website](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2015050803A1?cl=en) and [this website](https://books.google.com/books?id=DabL7gt_jwcC&pg=PA556&lpg=PA556&dq=plasma+jet+melt+glass&source=bl&ots=6Csqjtbhj2&sig=Ql5yP-hex9cU3lxHENvcIipMvVg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZudW-s6jOAhVq7IMKHZ0JAsYQ6AEILjAD#v=onepage&q=plasma%20jet%20melt%20glass&f=false). If this is helpful I can compose a full answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. By all means, fire up an answer ... but I'm really interested if there's a relationship between force and heat :0)

Comment: So....thermodynamics? ([This website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamics) has some information on that...I'm pretty sure that's defined as the relationship between work/force and heat.)

Comment: What attempt have you made to find an answer? (Apart from persuading heather to do the searching for you.) Have you tried this with your own light sabre?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of insufficient research effort.

Answer (score 6):

I have cut glass and ceramics with an ultrafast laser where the pulse duration was 100 fs, with pulse energy 1 mJ, 1,000 pulses per second. This means that the average power was 1 W, but when focused to a 200 um spot the instantaneous power was $10^{13}$ W/$cm^2$ or so.

There is no melting or cracking, but the material must be thin.  I was able to cut clean circles with microscope cover slips mounted on a stage.

So precise control of power delivered is the key.

This has [industrial applications.](http://www.industrial-lasers.com/articles/2015/02/femtosecond-laser-glass-cutting-yields-high-bending-strength-cut-quality.html)

So ask for the ultrafast light saber!